# export isn't complete

Tags: python, csv

This is my script:

```
from itertools import groupby
import operator
import csv

l = [['Cautus  B.V.', 'Cautus  B.V.plein 92', 'plein 92', '1129008', '10', 'AVB', 'Geachte mevrouw Daa', 'Mevrouw C.P. Daa', 'admin@planet.nl'] ,
['Cautus  B.V.', 'Cautus  B.V.Wei 9-11', 'Wei 9-11', '1019123', '10', 'AVB', 'Geachte mevrouw Daa', 'Mevrouw C.P. Daa', 'admin@planet.nl'] ,
['Cautus  B.V.', 'Cautus  B.V.plein 92', 'plein 92', '1129008', '10', 'BEDR', 'Geachte mevrouw Daa', 'Mevrouw C.P. Daa', 'admin@planet.nl'] ,
['Cautus  B.V.', 'Cautus  B.V.Wei 9-11', 'Wei 9-11', '1019123', '10', 'BEDR', 'Geachte mevrouw Daa', 'Mevrouw C.P. Daa', 'admin.@planet.nl'] ,
['De company', 'De companytiellaan 42', 'tiellaan 42', 'KD0022232', '13', 'AVB', 'Geachte heer Tigch', 'De heer I. Tigch', 'imre@company.nl'] ,
['De company', 'De companytiellaan 42', 'tiellaan 42', 'KD0022232', '13', 'DAS', 'Geachte heer Tigch', 'De heer I. Tigch', 'imre@company.nl'] ,
['Slever ', 'Slever klopt 42', 'klopt 42', 'KD2220115', '17', 'AVB', 'Geachte heer Slever', 'De heer T. Slever', 'info@company.com']]

sortkey = operator.itemgetter(1,5)
l_clean = sorted(l,key=sortkey)
l_final = [(k, list(v)) for k,v in groupby(l_clean, key = operator.itemgetter(1))]

for k,v in l_final:
   info_rest = v[0][:5]+v[0][5:]
   info_combine = map(operator.itemgetter(5),v)
   uniekid = k
   verz = info_combine
   naam = info_rest[0]
   risicoadr = info_rest[2]
   polisnummer = info_rest[3]
   relatienummer = info_rest[4]
   aanhef = info_rest[6]
   contactpersoon = info_rest[7]
   emailadr = info_rest[8]
   klantgegevens = [uniekid,naam,verz,risicoadr,polisnummer,relatienummer,aanhef,contactpersoon,emailadr,]

import csv
   with open('export.csv', 'w') as f:
       writer = csv.writer(f)
       writer.writerows(klantgegevens)
```

When i write i get this as a result in my .csv file:

```
S   l   e   v   e   r       k   l   o   p   t       4   2
```

As you can see he only writes one street name in it.

Anyone who can help me with this?

Comment: What do you expect this to do? You are only writing one row to your CSV file. If you wanted it to write more than one row, you should move `writer.writerows(...)` into your loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You only have *one* list (you reset `klantgegevens` on each loop), and you write that list as if it is a full set of multiple rows.

The CSV module sees that one list as a set of sequences, meaning that each string entry is seen as a sequence of individual characters, and that is what is then written to your csv file:

```
>>> klantgegevens
['Slever klopt 42', 'Slever ', ['AVB'], 'klopt 42', 'KD2220115', '17', 'Geachte heer Slever', 'De heer T. Slever', 'info@company.com']
>>> list(klantgegevens[0])
['S', 'l', 'e', 'v', 'e', 'r', ' ', 'k', 'l', 'o', 'p', 't', ' ', '4', '2']
```

You can write each row separately while collecting the `klantgegevens` lists:

```
import csv
with open('export.csv', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for k,v in l_final:
       info_rest = v[0][:5]+v[0][5:]
       info_combine = map(operator.itemgetter(5),v)
       uniekid = k
       verz = info_combine
       naam = info_rest[0]
       risicoadr = info_rest[2]
       polisnummer = info_rest[3]
       relatienummer = info_rest[4]
       aanhef = info_rest[6]
       contactpersoon = info_rest[7]
       emailadr = info_rest[8]
       klantgegevens = [uniekid,naam,verz,risicoadr,polisnummer,relatienummer,aanhef,contactpersoon,emailadr,]
       writer.writerow(klantgegevens)
```

Now the list will be treated as a sequence of columns, writing each line as you complete it.

Alternatively, you'd have to collect each `klantgegevens` list into a results list:

```
results = []    
for k,v in l_final:
    # processing
    klantgegevens = [uniekid,naam,verz,risicoadr,polisnummer,relatienummer,aanhef,contactpersoon,emailadr,]
    results.append(klantgegevens)
```

Then write that list of lists to your CSV file:

```
import csv
with open('export.csv', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(results)
```